# MVC 4 Web Api Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I want to make an insertion from a distant client for that I need to send data via http.
I can use the `getPerformances()` correctly with an `httpClient` `api/performances?date={0}`

I want to ask if my `postPorformances()` implemntation inside my `PerformancesController` is corrrect and if it is how to call it from a client?

Here is my implementation:

```
public class PerformancesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/performances
        public IEnumerable<Performance> getPerformances(DateTime date)
        {
            return DataProvider.Instance.getPerformances(date);
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage postPerformances(Performance p)
        {
            DataProvider.Instance.insertPerformance(p);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Performance>(HttpStatusCode.Created, p);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

```
public class Performance {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public decimal Value {get;set;}
}
```

I have tried this one but I'm note sure:

```c#
  private readonly HttpClient _client;
  string request = String.Format("api/performances");
  var jsonString = "{\"Date\":" + p.Date + ",\"Value\":" + p.Value + "}";
  var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var message = await _client.PutAsync(request, httpContent);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the `HttpClient` to call this method:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com");
    var result = client.PostAsync("/api/performances", new
    {
        id = 1,
        date = DateTime.Now,
        value = 1.5
    }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.writeLine("Performance instance successfully sent to the API");
    }
    else
    {
        string content = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine("oops, an error occurred, here's the raw response: {0}", content);
    }
}
```

In this example I am using the generic `PostAsync<T>` method allowing me to send any object as second parameter and choose the media type formatter. Here I have used an anonymous object mimicking the same structure as your `Performance` model on the server and the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`. You could of course share this `Performance` model between the client and the server by placing it in a contracts project so that changes on the server would also be automatically reflected on the client.

Side remark: C# naming convention dictates that method names should start with a capital letter. So `getPerformances` should be `GetPerformances` or even better `Get` and `postPerformances` should be `PostPerformances` or even better `Post`.

Comment: If the ap/performances call takes a long time, you might want to set the client.Timeout before making the call